# Convert a data frame with Product_Type, Date and Demand to timeseries object?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

```
Product_Code    Date    Order_Demand
Product_1904    09-01-2017  4000
Product_0250    09-01-2017  148
Product_0471    09-01-2017  30
Product_1408    06-01-2017  1000
Product_0689    06-01-2017  200
Product_0689    06-01-2017  300
Product_1926    06-01-2017  2
Product_1938    06-01-2017  20
```

I am new to R. I want to convert the above data to a time series object ts, such that the rownames will be Product_Code and column names will be months or quarters. Kindly help me!!

Comment: Please add a reproducible example with your data or similar data

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to properly copy-paste the table, but the first column is "Product_Code", second column is "Date" and third column is "Demand". Kindly help how to convert such a table to ts (timeseries) object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you,

```
library(xts)
library(lubridate)

# dummmy data
test_data <- data.frame(
  Product_Code = c("Product_1904","Product_0250","Product_0471"),
  Date = mdy(c("09-01-2017","09-02-2017","09-03-2017")),
  Order_Demand = c(4000,148,30)
)

# convert dummy data into xts time series
xts::xts(test_data, order.by = test_data$Date) -> time_series_data

str(time_series_data)

An ‘xts’ object on 2017-09-01/2017-09-03 containing:
  Data: chr [1:3, 1:3] "Product_1904" "Product_0250" "Product_0471" "2017-09-01" "2017-09-02" "2017-09-03" "4000" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "Product_Code" "Date" "Order_Demand"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

From next time please use `dput()` and copy paste the result from the R terminal to provide the data.